# INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 while sending a blob through websocket

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to send through websockets a blob obtained through `dataURItoBlob(canvas.get()[0].toDataURL('image/png'));` in this way:

```
connection.send(JSON.stringify({
                cmd: "fwd",
                msg: msg,
                p_id: worker_id,
            })
```

where `msg` is the blob just created. If I try to send the blob by doing `msg = ""+msg` it works but it only sends the string `[Object object]`, which is useless for me.

If I try to do `msg = JSON.stringify(msg)` before sending it, it gives me the same error, as in the topic title.

If I try to send the data without encapsulating it in a blob (as `msg = canvas.get()[0].toDataURL('image/png');` ) I have the same behaviour explained above.

What can I do to send the data? Thanks

Comment: Is the error caused by stringify or by send?

Comment: The error appears in `send()`

Answer (score 14):

***JSON.stringify()*** is **perfectly OK** and it is the way to do it.

The "INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11" error **is caused by executing send() message before the socket is connected**. *WebSocket.send()* should be triggered after *WebSocket.onopen()* event handler was triggered (or inside of that handler):

```
this.ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1234", "base64");
this.ws.onopen = function() { this.send({"type":"init_req"});};
```